# Invalid operand of types 'long long int' to binary 'operator%'

Tags: c++, int, long-long

i am in C++ and I get this error:

```
bool comprovarCodi(long long num, int DC){
bool codi_correcte;
int i=0, suma_senars=0, suma_parells=0, suma_total=0, desena_superior, DC_calculat, cont=0;
while(num!=0){
    num=num/10;
    cont++;
    i++;    
}
if(cont==12){
    for(int j=1; j<12; j=j+2){
        suma_senars=suma_senars+num%pow(10,j);
```

I don't know why, I believe "num" is an integer so I can use the operator "%".

Somebody knows why it fails?

Thank you

Comment: `pow` returns `double`, you cannot apply `%` to `long long` and `double`.

Comment: You need to read the _whole_ error message, not just half of it.

Comment: (pow also exists for float and long double, but yes, no integer return type)

Comment: The problema is that I need to get every digit of a number of 12 digits. That is why I use the long long. Do you know another method to do it?

Comment: @user3894819 As said already by multiple people, the problem is not `long long`, but `double` (`pow`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `pow` for this sort of thing.

```
long long pow_ten = 10;
for(int j=1; j<12; j=j+2)
{
   suma_senars=suma_senars+num%pow_ten;
   pow_ten *= 100;
}
```

Not only will this be faster, it will also calculate correctly, rather than `pow` which may well use something like `exp(log(x) * y)` to calculate `x ** y` - and thus not always come up with precisely the number you wanted - particularly if you cast it back to integer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast to int first
`suma_senars = suma_senars + num % (int)pow(10,j);`
better:
`suma_senars += num % (int)pow(10,j);`
clearer:
`suma_senars += num % ( (int)pow(10,j) );`

Comment: Actually, I think your clearer line is less clear than your better line -- extra redundant parenthesis generally make things harder to read IMO.

Comment: It is a bad idea, since you can easily get unexpected result due to cutting of the floating part. `(int)9.9999` is `9`, not `10`. In general, as **@Mats** said, do not use `pow` in such scenarios.